# Walking in space shuttle in 2001: A Space Odyssey

Tags: spaceship, 2001-a-space-odyssey

There is a scene in *2001: A Space Odyssey* where we can see the lead actor running or jogging in the space shuttle bound for Jupiter and there is a scene in the beginning where an air hostess uses velcro kind of shoes and then spins 360 degrees and then walks into another room.

Why does she need a magnetic or velcro shoes whereas the person jogging does not? Is it related to speed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The *Discovery One* (the space ship bound to Jupiter) has a [centrifuge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_One#Centrifuge) that provides [artificial gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity#Rotation) through rotation in a small section of the ship.

Comment: *"Is it related to speed?"*  On a side note.  If the Hostess had been able to run fast enough around the inner ring, she would have created her own centripetal effect.  If the Jogger goes in the direction the 'big tube' is spinning, he'd feel heavier, opposite, lighter..

Comment: @Andrew: If you run fast enough, you can [make your own centrifuge](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Awe6vOXURpY&feature=youtu.be&t=19s).

Comment: The set design behind this was incredible too!! That whole film’s undertaking still blows away anything done since.